# Displaying first level parent and co-children of that parent page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to set up a basic sidebar in Wordpress that has a couple conditions.

1. If it's a top level page, display the first level of children
2. If it's a child page, display the parent as well as its siblings

I'm getting some results with this, but it's adding pages that aren't directly children.

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
else
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
   <?php echo '<h4>Explore ' . get_the_title($parent[1]) . '</h4>';  ?> 
<?php echo $children; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this question

1. Limit the children to just 1 level: You can pass `depth` into `wp_list_pages()`, to can specify the level of hierarchy.
2. If its a child page, include the parent - but *only* the parent and not its siblings - in the list. 
   To add the parent to the list, you need to do things a little differently - you must first compile a a list of the ids of all the pages you want to get, and pass that into wp_list_pages.

The following code is untested, but the logic should be right:

```
if($post->post_parent){
    // get a list of all the children of the parent page
    $pages = get_pages(array('child_of'=>$post->post_parent));

    if ($pages) {
      // get the ids for the pages in a comma-delimited string
      foreach ($pages as $page) 
           $page_ids[] = $page->ID;
      $siblings = implode(',',$page_ids);

      // $pages_to_get is a string with all the ids we want to get, i.e. parent & siblings
      $pages_to_get = $post->post_parent.','.$siblings;

      // use "include" to get only the pages in our $pages_to_get
       $children = wp_list_pages("include=".$pages_to_get."&echo=0");
    }

}
else{
    // get pages that direct children of this page: depth=1
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&depth=1&echo=0");
}

// display the children:
if ($children) { 
    echo '<h4>Explore ' . get_the_title($parent[1]) . '</h4>';  
    echo $children; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately nothing seems to be showing up. I don't see any syntax issues off hand, and tried tweaking it around a bit, but haven't had any luck. It's currently showing nothing on the top level pages and children pages.

Comment: If you add `var_dump`s for the variables at each stage, are you getting any results at any point?

Comment: @TrevorCollinson I've just tested it and its working perfectly for me. Did you maybe not notice that I didn't include the rest of your code that displays `$children` in my answer?I only changed the `if - else` so I only included those lines. I've updated my answer to add them, just in case you forgot to keep them :-)

Comment: Ah yes, I totally failed to combine them. It's working perfectly. Much appreciated!!

Comment: There it is! I was looking for the solved button. Years of turning to Stackoverflow and this was my first question. Thanks for helping make this site what it is.